# Save, for each row in df, N-1 columns into a new line and the N-th column into another line (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, io

I have a very big dataframe and I am looking for an efficient way to store it as a formated text file as shown bellow.

Consider the following example dataframe:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 

     id    etc      data
0    12    info12   text12
1    34    info34   text34


desired output in txt: 
      # 12 info12
      text12
      # 34 info34
      text34
```

Is there a quick way to do this and avoid multiple inefficient `for` conditions?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, it's syntactically incorrect

Comment: `df[['data']].to_csv('the_file.csv')`?

Comment: @roganjosh I rephrased my question, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

pandas has a built in method for this.

it look like this:

```py
# some large dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],columns=['a','b','c'])

# save as a csv file
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

...that is all you need.

Comment: nope, not really!

Comment: @media_etc:  what do you mean please ?

Comment: don't know what else can I do? I think my question is perfectly clear and for those who cannot read the title, there is also an illustration (even clearer). Your solution merely saves the dataframe.